# LWC component when placed [object object ] is visible

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I have an issue regarding LWC component when placed [object object ] is visible. I'm attaching all my files here. Please help me in resolving the issue.

### my js class

```
import { LightningElement,wire,api } from 'lwc';
import relatedRec from '@salesforce/apex/DisplayParent.getServiceOrderrec';
export default class RelatedList extends LightningElement {

    @api recordId;
    records;
    error;
     
     
    columns=[
        {label:'Client Company Name',fieldName:'Company',text:'text'},
        {label:'Client Name',fieldName:'Name',text:'text'}
        ];
     
    @wire(relatedRec,{childId:'$recordId'})
    listRecords({data,error}){
        if(data){
            this.records=data;
        }
        else if(error){
            this.error=error;
        }
    }

}
```

my html class

```
<template>

    <lightning-card title="Service Order Details">
        <template if:true={records}>
            <lightning-datatable data={records} columns={columns} key-field="Id" ></lightning-datatable>
        </template>
        <template if:true={error}>{error}</template>
    </lightning-card>
    
</template>
```

apex contoller class

```apex
public with sharing class DisplayParent{
     @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Lead> getServiceOrderrec(Id LeadId){
        List<Lead> relatedRec=new List<Lead>();
        if (Schema.sObjectType.Lead.isAccessible() && Schema.sObjectType.Lead.isQueryable()) {
        Lead lerec=[SELECT Service_order__c FROM Lead  WHERE Id=:LeadId];
        
        if (Schema.sObjectType.Lead.isAccessible() && Schema.sObjectType.Lead.isQueryable()) {
       relatedRec=[SELECT Id,Company,Name FROM Lead WHERE Id=:lerec.Service_order__c];
        }
    }
        return relatedRec;
    }
    
}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems you are getting some error, check what is the error you are getting in LWC.

Comment: SarojBera can u please suggest me what is the error

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `childId` is used in JavaScript, but `LeadId` is used in Apex. That means that query for `Lead lerec` will not match any rows, and throw a "No rows for assignment" error. `[object Object]` is being displayed because `error` has a structure, but simply using `{error}` will call `toString` on the object, which will render as `[object Object]`.

So, to fix the problem:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Service Order Details">
        <template lwc:if={records}>
            <lightning-datatable data={records} columns={columns} key-field="Id" ></lightning-datatable>
        </template>
        <template lwc:if={error}>{error.message}</template>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

```
import { LightningElement,wire,api } from 'lwc';
import relatedRec from '@salesforce/apex/DisplayParent.getServiceOrderrec';
export default class RelatedList extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    records;
    error;
    columns=[
        {label:'Client Company Name',fieldName:'Company',text:'text'},
        {label:'Client Name',fieldName:'Name',text:'text'}
        ];
    @wire(relatedRec,{LeadId:'$recordId'})
    listRecords({data,error}){
        if(data){
            this.records=data;
        }
        else if(error){
            this.error=error;
        }
    }
}
```

```
public with sharing class DisplayParent{
  @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
  public static List<Lead> getServiceOrderrec(Id LeadId){
    if (LeadId != null && Schema.sObjectType.Lead.isAccessible() && Schema.sObjectType.Lead.isQueryable()) {
      Lead lerec=[SELECT Service_order__c FROM Lead  WHERE Id=:LeadId];
      return [SELECT Id,Company,Name FROM Lead WHERE Id=:lerec.Service_order__c];
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

This will take care of most of your main problems, although you should also consider the case where LeadId is not null but the user cannot query the record for some reason.

Comment: Thank you sfdcfox this resolved my issue.